# How to add numbers to asp response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I am very novice with asp. This is my code:

```
response.write("<script>")
do until rs.EOF
  for each x in rs.Fields
    response.write(" var ")
    response.write("CC=" & x.value)
  next
  rs.MoveNext
loop
response.write("</script>")
```

How can I make the output be `var CC1= x.value`, then have the next loop return be `var CC2=x.value` and so on???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment a counter variable. 
You would also need a ";"

```
response.write("<script>")

dim counter: counter = 0

do until rs.EOF
  for each x in rs.Fields
    counter = counter + 1
    response.write "var CC" & counter & "=" & x.value & ";"
  next
  rs.MoveNext
loop
```

The Array form: `var CC[];` ... `CC[counter] =` would be an alternative.